# Sitecore Docker Installation Issue - A connection attempt failed

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up the `Sitecore Docker container` but when I try to execute the `docker-compose up -d` command, the command executes and starts pulling the images but after some time I get below error. Any idea what's wrong I am doing?

Error:

```
read tcp 192.168.1.105:1993->204.79.197.219:443: wsarecv: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

[image]

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: Could you please check if Port 443 is not getting used while you're running the docker-compose command

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check two things here.

1. Check if the path of the specific image is not correct. To do this, you need to go to your `.env` file and verify the path of the images. Also, you can verify in the `docker-compose.override.yml`.
2. There can be an issue of memory limit. In this case, you need to increase the limit. So if you have something like this in your .env file, you can increase those. For example this.

   ```
   SQL_MEM_LIMIT=3GB

   SOLR_MEM_LIMIT=2GB

   CM_MEM_LIMIT=4GB
   ```

You can also check your `docker-compose.override.yml`, in case you have hardcoded these limits. For example, you have to add the `mem_limit` variable something like this.

```
mssql:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-mssql:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/mssql
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-mssql:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        SPE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY}spe-assets:${SPE_VERSION}
        SXA_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY}sxa-xp1-assets:${SXA_VERSION}
        SPS_ASSETS: ${SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY}sitecore-sps-integration-xp0-assets:${SPS_ASSET_VERSION}
                    
    mem_limit: ${SQL_MEM_LIMIT}   #Define the Memory limit here. 
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_DATA_PATH}\mssql:c:\data
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened due to a Company Network issue or my Laptop was too busy running other applications, I restarted the machine and followed the exact same steps again (I was referring to one of the Plural sight Video guides)  and this time it worked. Thanks for all the comments and advice.

Comment: I think this is not an answer, so you may need to mention this in the comments. Thanks